# Toggling "hidden" attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to show and hide an <input> element based on the <select> value.
I found a way to do it, but I think it's so much code for a simple purpose. What could be a better way?

Here's the code I wrote without using any frameworks:

```js
let menu = document.getElementById("rank_current")
let value = menu.value
menu.addEventListener('change', function() {
  value = menu.value
  for (i = 0; i < menu.childElementCount; i++) {
    if (menu.options[i].classList.contains("select-mythic") && menu.options[i].value == value) {
      document.getElementById("target").removeAttribute("hidden")
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="rank_current">
  <option value="select">--Select Rank--</option>
  <option value="grandmaster">Grandmaster</option>
  <option value="epic">Epic</option>
  <option value="legend">Legend</option>
  <option class="select-mythic" value="mythic">Mythic</option>
  <option class="select-mythic" value="mythical_honor">Mythical Honor</option>
</select>
<input id="target" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Stars" hidden>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can significantly shorten your code, by making your `change` handler a one-liner. Also there is no need to loop through the options here.

```js
document.getElementById("rank_current").addEventListener('change',
  ({target}) => document.getElementById("target").hidden = !target.value.startsWith('mythic')
);
```

```html
<select id="rank_current">
  <option value="select">--Select Rank--</option>
  <option value="grandmaster">Grandmaster</option>
  <option value="epic">Epic</option>
  <option value="legend">Legend</option>
  <option class="select-mythic" value="mythic">Mythic</option>
  <option class="select-mythic" value="mythical_honor">Mythical Honor</option>
</select>
<input id="target" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Stars" hidden>
```

If your real world scenario suggests you'd rather rely on the `class` attribute value, here's a solution that utilizes that. This one would even work for a `select multiple` and only show the input if all of the selected options have that CSS class.

```js
document.getElementById("rank_current").addEventListener('change',
  ({ target }) => document.getElementById("target").hidden = ![...target.selectedOptions].every(option => option.classList.contains('select-mythic'))
);
```

```html
<select id="rank_current">
  <option value="select">--Select Rank--</option>
  <option value="grandmaster">Grandmaster</option>
  <option value="epic">Epic</option>
  <option value="legend">Legend</option>
  <option class="select-mythic" value="mythic">Mythic</option>
  <option class="select-mythic" value="mythical_honor">Mythical Honor</option>
</select>
<input id="target" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Stars" hidden>
```

Let me know if you need a more in-depth explanation of the code of either of the solutions.

Comment: In the second solution, what is the syntax used in `[...target.selectedOptions]` and if you can provide a link for the documentation. thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax - spreading a nodelist into an array to allow array functions on it